# Cents symbol in phonology

Tags: phonology, terminology, ipa, transcription, phonetic-symbols

In examining Chol's [phonology](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/ling.1974.12.132.87), I came across the (old?) cents symbol ¢ ([with a slanted line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_%28currency%29)) as a phoneme symbol.

I have not been able to track what it corresponds to in IPA terms, but I suspect it's the aspirated affricate [t͡sʰ].

Is anyone familiar with this symbol to confirm or discard that it's such affricate in IPA?

Comment: Your first link brings to a page that needs a login. If you can replace it, please do it, otherwise just remove it. :)

Comment: I fixed the link, Alenanno.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pullum and Ladusaw](http://books.google.com/books?id=PHb7ug_U_O0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) say that symbol (they call it a "slashed C") represents a voiceless alveolar or dental (centrally released) affricate. The usual IPA notation is [ts] (Pullum and Ladusaw 1996, p. 29).

Comment: Right.  And if I can add a bit of explanation for amp's benefit, note in particular that the cents symbol doesn't generally imply anything about aspiration one way or another.  The Chol phoneme written /¢/ is sometimes (or always?) aspirated according to the text linked above, but the author has chosen to treat that as a mere phonetic detail and use the plain symbol.  This is like how the English phoneme written /ʃ/ is almost always pronounced with lip-rounding, but is rarely written with a superscript w because the lip-rounding is just a phonetic detail.